# content privacy policy refuses appending script to DOM

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I'm appending some scripts to the active tab using Firefox SDK addon,

```
// main.js
tabs.activeTab.attach({
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("js/loader.js") ]
});
```

and the *loader.js* creates a new script according to the URL and title of the website it's working on, then appends the new script file like *counter.js* to body. executing loader works fine, but the content privacy policy of the website refuses appending counter.js . here is the error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://example.com/counter.js ("default-src http://www.pinterest.com:80 https://*.pinterest.com:443 https://*.pinimg.com:443 http://*.pinterest.com:80 http://*.pinimg.com:80 http://*.google.com:80 http://connect.facebook.net:80 http://*.google-analytics.com:80 https://*.facebook.com:443 http://*.facebook.com:80 http://www.googleadservices.com:80 http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80 http://*.tiles.mapbox.com:80 http://*.4sqi.net:80 http://*.online-metrix.net:80 http://akwww.polyvorecdn.com:80 https://www.polyvore.com:443 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'").
```

I've done this before for a Chrome extension and It's possible. but question is how to append the scripts by Firefx SDK addon?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe Firefox and Chrome interpret the page policies differently, with Firefox assuming that "no means no".

Comment: @Pointy Maybe, but I need to find a way!

Comment: Can we see how you're appending the scripts and what URLs you're trying it on?

Comment: @willlma thanks, I've added some more info

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to attach scripts to pages with specific URLs, you're better off using a [`PageMod`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) than attaching to tabs. It would be useful to see most of your code and know a little bit about what you intend to do to give you the best answer, but if a `PageMod` isn't what you're looking for, here are some different scenarios.

There are two ways of going about this. The one that I would do is to simply attach both scripts immediately, like so:

**main.js**

```
tabs.activeTab.attach({
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("js/loader.js"), data.url("js/counter.js") ]
});
```

**counter.js**

```
var i = 0;
function count() {
  i++;
}
```

**loader.js**

```
if (titleIsValid() && urlIsValid()) {
  count();
}
```

Because all of your files are stored locally, I wouldn't worry too much about attaching a lot of JS files to a lot of pages. You just need to structure your *count.js* so that doesn't execute the code automatically.

---

If you really want to attach the JS file only if those conditions apply, you can do this:

**main.js**

```
var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
  contentScriptFile: data.url("js/loader.js")
});

worker.port.on('attachCounter', function() {
  worker.tab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: (data.url("js/counter.js")
  });
});
```

**loader.js**

```
if (titleIsValid() && urlIsValid()) {
  self.port.emit('attachCounter');
}
```

Read more about [communicating between content scripts and main scripts from `tab/attach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#From_Tab.attach%28%29)

---

If the reason you attached the script to the page is to interact with page scripts that are already on the page (and the exact reason Firefox is telling you it's unsafe), then read about [interacting with page scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts).

Comment: Thanks dear @willlma, I've tried all of these ways before. but because I've wrote the loader and counter scripts to work as bookmark, and I didn't know about this policy, I can't use them. I think I have t make changes in those scripts.